# Using Optuna XGBoostPruningCallback with mglogloss function

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, optuna

I'm trying to use Optuna for a `XGBoostClassifier` from an example from [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/para24/xgboost-stepwise-tuning-using-optuna/notebook) article and i simplyfied it cause it got's lots of steps I don't care about, but I keep on receiving a `KeyError: 'validation_0-mlogloss'` when I call `XGBoostPruningCallback`:

```py
def nostep_objective(trial,params=dict()):
    data, target = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)
    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.25)
    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_x, label=train_y)
    dtest = xgb.DMatrix(test_x, label=test_y)
    # class_weight = (y.shape[0] - np.sum(y)) / np.sum(y)

    ## Initial Learning Parameters
    params['learning_rate'] = 0.1
    params['num_boost_round'] = 1000

# if group == '1':
    params['max_depth'] = trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 2, 10)
    params['min_child_weight'] = trial.suggest_loguniform('min_child_weight',
                                                            1e-10, 1e10)

# if group == '2':
    params['subsample'] = trial.suggest_uniform('subsample', 0, 1)
    params['colsample_bytree'] = trial.suggest_uniform('colsample_bytree', 0, 1)

# if group == '3':
    params['learning_rate'] = trial.suggest_uniform('learning_rate', 0, 0.1)
    params['num_boost_round'] = trial.suggest_int('num_boost_round', 100, 1000)

    # Add a callback for pruning.
    pruning_callback = XGBoostPruningCallback(trial, "validation_0-mlogloss")
    
    cv_scores = xgb.cv(params, dtrain, nfold=5,
                       stratified=True,
                    #    feval=score,
                       early_stopping_rounds=10,
                       callbacks=[pruning_callback],
                       seed=0)
   return cv_scores

study = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize')
study.optimize(lambda trial: objective(trial, x_train, y_train,
                                           params))
print(study.best_trial)
```

stacktrace:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/juanc/Documents/betta/practice/experimentacion/model_hyperparameters.py in line 32
     414     # print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", cv_scores)
     415     # return cv_scores['test-' + '-mean'].values[-1]
     417 study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')
---> 418 study.optimize(lambda trial: nostep_objective(trial, x_train, y_train,
     419                                            params))
     421 print(study.best_trial)

File ~/virtualenvs/experimentacion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optuna/study/study.py:425, in Study.optimize(self, func, n_trials, timeout, n_jobs, catch, callbacks, gc_after_trial, show_progress_bar)
    321 def optimize(
    322     self,
    323     func: ObjectiveFuncType,
   (...)
    330     show_progress_bar: bool = False,
    331 ) -> None:
    332     """Optimize an objective function.
    333 
    334     Optimization is done by choosing a suitable set of hyperparameter values from a given
   (...)
    422             If nested invocation of this method occurs.
    423     """
--> 425     _optimize(
    426         study=self,
    427         func=func,
    428         n_trials=n_trials,
    429         timeout=timeout,
    430         n_jobs=n_jobs,
    431         catch=tuple(catch) if isinstance(catch, Iterable) else (catch,),
    432         callbacks=callbacks,
    433         gc_after_trial=gc_after_trial,
    434         show_progress_bar=show_progress_bar,
    435     )

File ~/virtualenvs/experimentacion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py:66, in _optimize(study, func, n_trials, timeout, n_jobs, catch, callbacks, gc_after_trial, show_progress_bar)
     64 try:
     65     if n_jobs == 1:
---> 66         _optimize_sequential(
     67             study,
     68             func,
     69             n_trials,
     70             timeout,
     71             catch,
     72             callbacks,
     73             gc_after_trial,
     74             reseed_sampler_rng=False,
     75             time_start=None,
     76             progress_bar=progress_bar,
     77         )
     78     else:
     79         if n_jobs == -1:

File ~/virtualenvs/experimentacion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py:163, in _optimize_sequential(study, func, n_trials, timeout, catch, callbacks, gc_after_trial, reseed_sampler_rng, time_start, progress_bar)
    160         break
    162 try:
--> 163     frozen_trial = _run_trial(study, func, catch)
    164 finally:
    165     # The following line mitigates memory problems that can be occurred in some
    166     # environments (e.g., services that use computing containers such as GitHub Actions).
    167     # Please refer to the following PR for further details:
    168     # https://github.com/optuna/optuna/pull/325.
    169     if gc_after_trial:

File ~/virtualenvs/experimentacion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py:251, in _run_trial(study, func, catch)
    244         assert False, "Should not reach."
    246 if (
    247     frozen_trial.state == TrialState.FAIL
    248     and func_err is not None
    249     and not isinstance(func_err, catch)
    250 ):
--> 251     raise func_err
    252 return frozen_trial

File ~/virtualenvs/experimentacion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py:200, in _run_trial(study, func, catch)
    198 with get_heartbeat_thread(trial._trial_id, study._storage):
    199     try:
--> 200         value_or_values = func(trial)
    201     except exceptions.TrialPruned as e:
    202         # TODO(mamu): Handle multi-objective cases.
    203         state = TrialState.PRUNED

/home/juanc/Documents/betta/practice/experimentacion/model_hyperparameters.py in line 32, in (trial)
     414     # print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", cv_scores)
     415     # return cv_scores['test-' + '-mean'].values[-1]
     417 study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')
---> 418 study.optimize(lambda trial: nostep_objective(trial, x_train, y_train,
     419                                            params))
     421 print(study.best_trial)

/home/juanc/Documents/betta/practice/experimentacion/model_hyperparameters.py in line 22, in nostep_objective(trial, X, y, group, params)
     406 # Add a callback for pruning.
     407 pruning_callback = XGBoostPruningCallback(trial, "validation_0-mlogloss")
---> 408 cv_scores = xgb.cv(params, dtrain, nfold=5,
     409                    stratified=True,
     410                 #    feval=score,
     411                    early_stopping_rounds=10,
     412                    callbacks=[pruning_callback],
     413                    seed=0)

File ~/virtualenvs/experimentacion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/training.py:540, in cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, nfold, stratified, folds, metrics, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, fpreproc, as_pandas, verbose_eval, show_stdv, seed, callbacks, shuffle, custom_metric)
    537     break
    538 booster.update(i, obj)
--> 540 should_break = callbacks_container.after_iteration(booster, i, dtrain, None)
    541 res = callbacks_container.aggregated_cv
    542 for key, mean, std in cast(List[Tuple[str, float, float]], res):

File ~/virtualenvs/experimentacion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/callback.py:247, in CallbackContainer.after_iteration(self, model, epoch, dtrain, evals)
    245     metric_score = [(n, float(s)) for n, s in metric_score_str]
    246     self._update_history(metric_score, epoch)
--> 247 ret = any(c.after_iteration(model, epoch, self.history)
    248           for c in self.callbacks)
    249 return ret

File ~/virtualenvs/experimentacion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/callback.py:247, in (.0)
    245     metric_score = [(n, float(s)) for n, s in metric_score_str]
    246     self._update_history(metric_score, epoch)
--> 247 ret = any(c.after_iteration(model, epoch, self.history)
    248           for c in self.callbacks)
    249 return ret

File ~/virtualenvs/experimentacion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optuna/integration/xgboost.py:69, in XGBoostPruningCallback.after_iteration(self, model, epoch, evals_log)
     66         else:
     67             evaluation_results[key] = scores[-1]
---> 69 current_score = evaluation_results[self._observation_key]
     70 self._trial.report(current_score, step=epoch)
     71 if self._trial.should_prune():

KeyError: 'validation_0-mlogloss'
```

I know the returning `cv_scores` are not ok to acces them by `optuna.optimize`, but that's a future problem.

Comment: I think the issue is i'm using `xbv.cv` and i do not understand which model that function actually uses. regression? classifier? other?